# Express Routing - how to require a file containing routes based on a URL Parameter?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I think I'm missing somthing simple...

Simply put, why does this work:

```
router.use('/:object', require('../v1/routes'));
```

But this not? [EDITED after Evert's answer, below]

```
function getRouter(req, res, next) {
    return require('../v1/routes');
}

router.use('/:object', getRouter());
```

where '../v1/routes' contains simply:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get('/', getAll);

function getAll(req, res, next) {
    res.send("Hello");
}

module.exports = router;
```

I was hoping to dynamically require the files using the API version as a filesystem base. Further up the chain I get the API version as part of the URL, so I was hoping to use that to drive the directory for the included routing file:

```
function getRouter(req, res, next) {
    return require(`../${req.params.apiVersion}/routes`);
}
```

Is there any way to include the router by require-ing its filepath dynamically?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT 1**
If I return my function call as I originally had it:

```
function getRouter(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.apiVersion);
    return require(`../${req.params.apiVersion}/routes`);
}

router.use('/:object', getRouter);
```

I actually get 'v1' written in the console log; so the parameters are there in fact, but the 'return require'... doesn't seem to be working as I imagined.

**EDIT 2 - SOLUTION**
Thanks to Evert's hints, I eventually got there:

```
function getRouter(req, res, next) {
    const dynamicRouter = require(`../${req.params.apiVersion}/routes`);
    return dynamicRouter(req, res, next);
}

router.use('/:object', getRouter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer just the first portion of this question.

These two are not equivalent:

```
// #1
router.use('/:object', require('../v1/routes'));

// #2
function getRouter() {
   return require('../v1/routes');
}
router.use('/:object', getRouter);
```

In the first snippet you are returning the result of `require` to `router.use`. In the second you are returning a *function* that returns the result of `getRouter()` to router.use.

To make these equivalent, the second one has to look like this:

```
router.use('/:object', getRouter());
```

Now we're calling `getRouter` instead of just passing it.

Overall I think this pattern is really strange though. Especially since you are creating another router in `v1/routes`. I don't think the top-level router does anything here. Just define this is a general middleware instead.

But, this should at least explain the difference between the first 2 calls.

Comment: Thanks Evert - in your initial response is correct - I needed to add the brackets to the function call. The issue is, that when I do that I get an error "req is not defined", because I'm not passing req to the function...  FYI, at the top level I have an API router, and a "normal" router. The API router has several sub-routers, based on version, and then further sub-routers based on the API object (customers, suppliers, etc. etc.)

Comment: Just for further clarification: It is working ok if I hardcode the required filepath. As soon as I need a variable in the filename I'm stuck.

Comment: With your update, you are calling `getRouter()` but without any arguments. The arguments do need to come from the request. You need to find a way to *call* the router not just return it .

Comment: And I think this is probably the question I was asking, just in a much more succinct form: How can I do that? The "req, res, next" arguments are not there to call the router at that time. They only exist when they get handled... adding an edit now to the question which may shed some light

Comment: @GarethL after your edit1, you are still returning the result of `require()`, not _calling_ the result of `require()`

Comment: Thanks Evert - problem solved. I appreciate the approach of leading me to the answer instead of giving it to me directly - it helps.